# Omniauth fails with invalid credentials only on iPhone Safari

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, ruby, mobile-safari, omniauth

Using 1.2.2 of Omniauth with Rails 4.1 - and all clients work perfectly with Google/Yahoo/LinkedIn - except iPhone Safari (iPad Safari works fine)

The error returned is always invalid_credentials and despite making dozens of changes relating to numerous google results/stack overflow threads/etc - I cannot find any way to get the iPhone to log in

The iPhone works fine in Chrome - only with Safari it fails

Our config is nothing more than provider :xyz, key, secret

Answer (score 1):

We had HTTP BASIC authentication running on the site to keep it from public eyes for the moment

On all clients apart from the iPhone Safari this hadn't caused any issues - for some reason on iPhone Safari the request must have been processed differently, I suspect causing multiple requests to the site and triggering some kind of CSRF or authentication issue - by making a number of random changes I managed to get the error to be a CSRF error instead of an authentication error

Removing the HTTP BASIC authentication resolved.